# How to slice BigQuery Array - Select all items except last

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have an array

```
SELECT [1,2,3]
```

I would like to select all elements except the last, so return

```
SELECT [1,2]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: ok, thanks have selected one. They all looked too convoluted for such a basic task, so I ended up working around the need for it

Comment: Wanna share your workaround with community?

Comment: can't remember, it was something specific to my use case, not necessarily solving the above problem directly

Comment: ok - no problem :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS (
  SELECT [1,2,3] original_array UNION ALL
  SELECT [101,102,103, 104, 105]
)
SELECT original_array,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT * EXCEPT(OFFSET)
    FROM test.original_array WITH OFFSET
    WHERE OFFSET < ARRAY_LENGTH(test.original_array) - 1
  ) new_array
FROM test
```

with result

```
Row original_array  new_array    
1   1               1    
    2               2    
    3        
2   101             101  
    102             102  
    103             103  
    104             104  
    105
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a query to simulate the behavior you want.

First I create a table with the array.

```
WITH table_test AS (SELECT [1,2,3] as ARRAY_TEST)
```

And after that I run a query using the `ORDINAL` function [1] to get every element from every position in the array except the last element `-1`.

```
SELECT ARRAY_TEST[ORDINAL(count_list)] 
  FROM UNNEST((SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_TEST)-1)) 
FROM table_test)) count_list, table_test
```

If you want to remove more values from the queue, change the value `-1`.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#offset_and_ordinal